# How to launch Bing Map with GPS Latlon

Tags: windows-phone-7

For Google map, I can use this code to get the Map by browser:
http:// maps.google.com/map? q= lat,lon.

For Bing map, How this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `BingMapsTask` to launch the bing maps app with a specified centre point (or search parameters - there is a [how-to article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394026%28v=vs.92%29), although the code would be as simple as:

```
BingMapsTask bingMapsTask = new BingMapsTask();

//Omit the Center property to use the user's current location.
bingMapsTask.Center = new GeoCoordinate(52.1, 1.2); // Substitute for your lat/long
bingMapsTask.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks. What I wanted is to send a Map link in SMS so anyone can open the map. The one you mentioned is open within the app.

Comment: It would have been helpful to mention that in your question, or tagged your question differently, to get answers closer to what you want to wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Having fired up Bing maps, I went to the share tab to get a full link to the current view and it gave this:

> http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=52.211442563609495~0.12835717468262953&lvl=14&dir=0&sty=r&eo=0&form=LMLTCC

cp is centrepoint followed by lat~long

lvl is the zoom level

sty is the style (r=road, b=bird's eye, h=aerial, etc)

Not too sure on the other parameters but leaving them out seems to still work:

> http://www.bing.com/maps/?cp=52.211442563609495~0.12835717468262953&lvl=14&sty=r

Comment: Thank. I tried the googlemap. I got a simple static map when user click on the link in SMS. What is this V=2 for bingMap? I see a similiar syntax like :"http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&where1=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Location).

Comment: I'm not sure on the v=2 - it doesn't seem to matter what you set it to. The where1 parameter is used for searching so where1=london will search for London.

Comment: Just a note that when openning that link on a Windows Phone, it'll get transferred into the Maps app automatically - on other phones and on PC's it should stick to the website.

Comment: @Grahram: Just tried that Bing Map link on WP7. I created a link in SMS. Click that link in SMS but IE in WP can not support it. It tried to show the DeskTop version Bing Map but it could not fully load and stuck. Oh well, will look for other solution. Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle I think I see what you mean - if your WP IE browser is set to Desktop View mode then it'll bring up the Bing maps desktop version. If it's in Mobile View mode then it'll push you into the Maps app - however how it sends the location is a little odd; it makes the Maps app do a search for a location nearby rather than sending the lat/long over so it doesn't always work!